# EF Core many to many relationship with class for join entity does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am following tutorials from Microsoft for .NET MVC and trying to deal with many to many relationship with EF Core.

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many](https://stackoverflow.com)

and

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/read-related-data?view=aspnetcore-8.0](https://stackoverflow.com)

Simple many to many relationship seems to work fine. Models are as follows:

```
public class Instructor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<Course> Courses { get; } = new ();
}
```

and

```
    public class Course
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CourseName { get; set; }
        public int Credit { get; set; }
        public List<Instructor> Instructors { get; } = new();
    }
```

at this point EF Core automatically creates the join table. When I manually fill the join table (can not seed data for join table) I can get the related data for each entity using `.Include()`.

However, when I create a third model

```
[Keyless]
public class CourseInstructor
{
    public int InstructorId { get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
}
```

I get an error upon adding the migration.

> The exception 'Cannot use table 'CourseInstructor' for entity type 'CourseInstructor' since it is being used for entity type 'CourseInstructor (Dictionary<string, object>)' and potentially other entity types, but there is no linking relationship.  Add a foreign key to 'CourseInstructor' on the primary key properties and pointing to the primary key on another entity type mapped to 'CourseInstructor'.'

I tried to add foreign keys to join entity, pointing at corresponding primary keys but I get the same error. Same problem persists when I add further navigations to and from join entity. I also tried to avoid keyless approach and added the key for the join entity to no avail.

According to same tutorials I am going to need this join `CourseInstructor` entity for creating and editing entries at later stage.

Is there a general problem or am I making some simple mistake? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A typical configuration for this case can be if you don't need any additional field to be stored in CourseInstructor class although you can modify it as per your setup.

```
public class InstructorConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Instructor>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Instructor> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Instructors");

        // Primary key
        builder.HasKey(i => i.Id);

        // Other property configurations...

        // Many-to-Many relationship with Course
        builder
            .HasMany(i => i.Courses)
            .WithMany(c => c.Instructors)
            .UsingEntity(j => j.ToTable("InstructorCourses"));
    }
}

public class CourseConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Course>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Course> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Courses");

        // Primary key
        builder.HasKey(c => c.Id);

        // Other property configurations...

        // Many-to-Many relationship with Instructor
        builder
            .HasMany(c => c.Instructors)
            .WithMany(i => i.Courses)
            .UsingEntity(j => j.ToTable("InstructorCourses"));
    }
}

public class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Instructor> Instructors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new InstructorConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new CourseConfiguration());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to add foreign keys to join entity, pointing at corresponding
> primary keys but I get the same error. Same problem persists when I
> add further navigations to and from join entity. I also tried to avoid
> keyless approach and added the key for the join entity to no avail

Well based on your description, code snippet along with the error message, it indicates that, [EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many#basic-many-to-many) is detecting a conflict between how you've defined the relationship and the existing join table.

Because,  In Entity Framework Core, when you create a many-to-many relationship, you don't necessarily need to define a separate entity for the join table, especially if you don't need to store additional properties in the join table. EF Core can handle the many-to-many relationship automatically.

However, if you want to have more control, therefore, to define realationship by yourself, you can try below configuration.

Let's have a look in practice how we can achieve that,

In order to implement that, you should get rid of [Keyless](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations#keyless-entity-types-characteristics), because, Keyless attribute is intended for entities that map to views or query tables, not for join entities.

So, to overcome that issue, you should make the composite key of InstructorId and CourseId the primary key of CourseInstructor.

For instance, you can do as following:

```
public class CourseInstructor
{
    public int InstructorId { get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; }

    public Instructor Instructor { get; set; }
    public Course Course { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return HashCode.Combine(InstructorId, CourseId);
    }
}
```

Within Model Builder:

Update your model builder configuration as following:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<CourseInstructor>()
        .HasKey(ci => new { ci.InstructorId, ci.CourseId });

    modelBuilder.Entity<CourseInstructor>()
        .HasOne(ci => ci.Instructor)
        .WithMany(i => i.Courses)
        .HasForeignKey(ci => ci.InstructorId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<CourseInstructor>()
        .HasOne(ci => ci.Course)
        .WithMany(c => c.Instructors)
        .HasForeignKey(ci => ci.CourseId);
}
```

**Note:** Now just remove previous migration files and re-create that, finally add your new migration, your error should resolved. If you want to see more example and explanation, please [refer to this official document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many#understanding-many-to-many-relationships)

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error on migration. Here are the steps I took to correct it. For focus, I'm only including the relevant Navigation Builder code.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CourseInstructor>().HasOne(d => d.Instructor).WithMany()
   .HasForeignKey(d => d.InstructorId)
   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
   .HasConstraintName("FK_CourseInstructor_InstructorId");

modelBuilder.Entity<CourseInstructor>().HasOne(d => d.Course).WithMany()
   .HasForeignKey(d => d.CourseId)
   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
   .HasConstraintName("FK_CourseInstructor_CourseId");

modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().HasMany(d => d.Instructors).WithMany(p => p.Courses)
    .UsingEntity("CourseInstructor");

modelBuilder.Entity<Instructor>().HasMany(d => d.Courses).WithMany(p => p.Instructors)
    .UsingEntity("CourseInstructor");
```

This is the code that generated the initial error. The thought was to set up the join table, then refer to it in `UsingEntity`. But by passing "CourseInstructor" as a string, it was trying to build another join table with the name that duplicated the one already defined above.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CourseInstructor>().HasOne(d => d.Instructor).WithMany()
   .HasForeignKey(d => d.InstructorId)
   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
   .HasConstraintName("FK_CourseInstructor_InstructorId");

modelBuilder.Entity<CourseInstructor>().HasOne(d => d.Course).WithMany()
   .HasForeignKey(d => d.CourseId)
   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
   .HasConstraintName("FK_CourseInstructor_CourseId");

modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().HasMany(d => d.Instructors).WithMany(p => p.Courses)
    .UsingEntity<CourseInstructor>();

modelBuilder.Entity<Instructor>().HasMany(d => d.Courses).WithMany(p => p.Instructors)
    .UsingEntity<CourseInstructor>();
```

When I switched from passing a string to referring by type, the error went away and the migration was successful.

P.S. That should be all it takes. But in my case, my tables were using Table-per-hierarchy inheritance which lead to additional, unwanted columns being added to the join table. So I needed one more step.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().HasMany(d => d.Instructors).WithMany(p => p.Courses)
    .UsingEntity<CourseInstructor>(
        j => j.HasOne(d => d.Instructor).WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.InstructorId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_CourseInstructor_InstructorId"),
        j => j.HasOne(d => d.Course).WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.CourseId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_CourseInstructor_CourseId"));

modelBuilder.Entity<Instructor>().HasMany(d => d.Courses).WithMany(p => p.Instructors)
    .UsingEntity<CourseInstructor>(
        j => j.HasOne(d => d.Course).WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.CourseId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_CourseInstructor_CourseId"),
        j => j.HasOne(d => d.Instructor).WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.InstructorId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_CourseInstructor_InstructorId"));
```

While I would prefer to define the foreign keys only once, I had to specifically define the right and left inside both `UsingEntity` statements in order to resolve any inheritance ambiguities.